# Hide Price on one specific Woocommerce Single Product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to hide the price on 1 specific Woocommerce Single Product page. I have tried a couple different code snippets I found but I am doing something wrong and nothing so far has worked. Can anyone give me the correct code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`woocommerce_get_price_html`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1664) filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price', 99, 2 );

function hide_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( 'your_product_slug' === $product->get_slug() ) {
        $price = '';
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new at this. How would I specify the product. The product id # is 7915. I believe the slug if it is also the Permalink is whidden-gunworks-custom-die. The price I am trying to hide is 0.00. I tried to do this below and added it to my functions.php file but it didn't work.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price', 99, 2 );

function hide_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( 'whidden-gunworks-custom-die' === $product->get_slug() ) {
        $price = '$ 0.00';
    }

    return $price;
}

Comment: @PaulKeffer price needs to stay empty `$price = ''`, your slug seems correct...

Comment: I believe I know the problem. The page is still currently a draft. I bet when I publish it your code will work. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Do you want to hide **all** prices which are $0.00 ?

Comment: Currently this is the only product like this that is 0.00. So I just needed to hide this particular product. I went ahead and published the product and then applied the your code and it worked perfectly! Thank you again!

Comment: @PaulKeffer Glad it helped you. Please, accept the answer !